# advanced for loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop, loops

I have a list of lists of lists(that last list doesn't really matter)

```
data = [[[['f', 0], 'C'], [['X', 0], 'X']],
[[['s', 1], 'X'], [['X', 0], 'X']]]
```

It is essentially a map with 4 quadrants. Currently I am iterating through it and updating it with

```
for i in data:
    for x in i:
        if x[0][0] == 'f':
            x[0][1] += 1
```

but I want to check a cell's neighbors. Is there a way to do it, when iterating by this or will i have to resolve to move through the list with integer keys?

Comment: Considered using a dict?

Comment: There are lots of ways to code this, but for clarity you might consider using a very simple "cell" class that knows it's neighbors.

Comment: I think your use of data structure is complicated, thus complicates the algorithm. If you can simplify the data structure, things will be easier. If that is not an option, please describe your data in details. For example, what do you mean by neighbors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unless you write something more complex that allows you to iterate over the elements that also gives you their neighbors, you will have to use absolute addressing of the elements.

If you are certain to always use a lists of lists (i.e. not just some other iterable), you can certainly make use of `enumerate` to get both the index *and* the element itself quickly:

```
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        # now you can access data[i][j-1], data[i+1][j] etc
```

So, I mentioned the “more complex” thing first and what you could do is make a generator which iterates over the cells automatically and *also* returns additional data like for example the left neighbor or something.

```
def myLeftNeighborGenerator(data):
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row):
            leftNeighbor = data[i][j-1] if j > 0 else None
            yield cell, leftNeighbor
```

Then you could just use that generator to magically get your data:

```
for x, left in myLeftNeighborGenerator(data):
    if x[0][0] == 'f':
        x[0][1] += 1
    if left is not None:
        # whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

If don't want to worry about having to keep track of integer keys yourself, but still want to use them, python has the [built in function `enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
>>> for index, value in enumerate(['my','list','of','stuff']):
...    print index, value
0 my
1 list
2 of
3 stuff
```

The `enumerate` function pairs the index of an item with that item, in every iteration of your `for` loop.